# Gulp: creating an array of every file in a folder

Tags: requirejs

I'm trying to create a gulp task that would scan all the files in a folder and create an array of these files. I'd like to automate some require js stuff and I'd like to use that array as a class'  dependencies array.

Within a gulp task I'd like to create an array of every file in a folder. Is there a way to do that?

I've tried to do several thing so far, this is my latest try:

```
gulp.src(['app/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(fileNames('javascript'));        

gulp.src('`enter code here`app.js')
    .pipe(gulpReplace('EVERY_FILE', JSON.stringify(fileNames.get('appjs', 'all'))))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
```

I'm trying to use 'gulp-filenames' here, but it just doesn't work. It should replace the 'EVERY_FILE' string in the app.js file.

Wonder if there is a way to do this with gulp.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with the "main-bower-files" package.